# Empty 'obsoletes' list when using YUM python module version 3.2.29

Tags: python, rpm, yum

I need to retrieve the list of packages that will be obsoleted by YUM transaction in Python. On Centos 7 with Python 2.7.5 and yum module 3.4.3 it works straight forward:

```
>>> import yum
>>> yb = yum.YumBase()
>>> txl = yb.installLocal('initial_patch-1-2.noarch.rpm')
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Examining initial_patch-1-2.noarch.rpm: initial_patch-1-2.noarch
Marking initial_patch-1-2.noarch.rpm to be installed
>>> txl
[<TransactionMember : initial_patch.noarch 0:1-2 - u (0x1906e60)>]
>>> txl[0]
<TransactionMember : initial_patch.noarch 0:1-2 - u (0x1906e60)>
>>> txl[0].obsoletes
[<RPMInstalledPackage : lzo-2.06-6.el7_0.2.x86_64 (0x1901bd0)>]
>>> txl[0].obsoletes[0].pkgtup
('lzo', 'x86_64', '0', '2.06', '6.el7_0.2')
```

So here we see that initial_patch-1-2.noarch.rpm obsoletes the lzo package (initial_patch is for test purposes). Then I am trying to execute the same piece of code on the target machine which has Python 2.6 with yum module 3.2.29 and I get this:

```
>>> import yum
>>> yb = yum.YumBase()
>>> txl = yb.installLocal('initial_patch-1-2.noarch.rpm')
Examining initial_patch-1-2.noarch.rpm: initial_patch-1-2.noarch
Marking initial_patch-1-2.noarch.rpm to be installed
>>> txl
[<TransactionMember : initial_patch.noarch 0:1-2 - u (0x12f0ab8)>]
>>> txl[0].pkgtup
('initial_patch', 'noarch', '0', '1', '2')
>>> txl[0].obsoletes
[]
```

You see the empty **obsoletes** list at the end, although the RPM installed is the same and both machines have the lzo package. I have no option upgrading Python or YUM on the target machine, so I would appreciate any idea for filling appropriately the **obsoletes** list.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of ">>> txl[0].obsoletes" seems to be dependent on whether
whatever package is to be obsoleted is actually installed (trying to
reproduce your example with a similar package containing an Obsoletes:)

This behavior is strictly what you asked for "list of packages that will be obsoleted" since a package that is not installed will not be obsoleted.

You might try extracting the possible Obsoletes: using the rpm-python API
directly from the packages. This is equivalent to "rpm -qp --obsoletes foo*.rpm"

Comment: In both cases I had the lzo package installed. However different YUM versions were giving different output. The workaround was, indeed, using rpm, but as python module. The drawback of this approach is you have to check if any of the obsoleted packages is installed, which is an additional yum transaction.